# Not Equal to returning false even if the variables are equal

Tags: excel, vba

I want to match a range's (A6:E40) first cell in "A" with the cell in "I". It inserts a cell row of A:E (on whatever row my x variable is on).

Sometimes I need to add from "A" to "I". This messes me up because I need my range data in B6:E40 to stay the same.

My Not equal to is returning false even though my data in that row is the same, and is executing my then statement.

Here is an example:

```vb
Sub TBmatch()

Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim x As Integer
Dim TF As String
Dim A As String
Dim I As String
x = 6

Set rng = Range("A6:E40")

Do While x > 5 And x < 40
    For Each row In rng.Rows
        TF = Range("H" & x)
        A = ("A" & x)
        I = ("I" & x)

        If I <> A Then Range("I" & x).Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
        If A <> I Then Cells(x, 9).Value = Cells(x, 1)
        If Range("A" & x) = "" Then Cells(x, 1).Value = Cells(x, 9)
       
        Range("H5").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H5:H88")
        TF = Range("H" & x)
         
        If TF = "False" Then Range("A" & x & ":E" & x).Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
        If Range("A" & x) = "" Then Cells(x, 1).Value = Cells(x, 9)
        
        Range("H5").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H5:H88")
        x = x + 1
    Next row
Loop
    
'Selection(1)
'Range("I6").Copy Destination:=Range("A6")
'Range("A6:E6").Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
End Sub
```

The {If I <> A} is returning True even when I does equal A.

[image: Document]

Comment: I am confused by your statement that "{If I <> A} is returning false even when I does equal A." If `I` equals `A` then `I<>A` *is* false. Why should it be true?

Comment: I apologize, I meant it is returning True, it should be returning false and not triggering the Then statement. @JohnColeman

Comment: Just because things *look* equal doesn't mean that they *are* equal. Perhaps they differ in white space, or in some other way that formatting doesn't allow to show up. `<>` tells you that the values that you think are equal are not in fact equal.

Comment: @JohnColeman Do you know a specific way to tell why they are not equal in VBA? I checked everything and even the excel function in the worksheet itself {=}  is marking them as true (meaning equal) but not in VBA.

Comment: `("A" & x)` _never be equal to_ `("I" & x)`

Comment: What does this mean? @EEM

Comment: `"A" & x` is a string which begins with `A`. That isn't how you get the values from a cell. Your question is close to being a typo.

Comment: You are trying to align the two lists of accounts, correct? If an account is listed in Column I but not A:E, you want to insert it and shift A:E down and if an account is on the A:E list but not Column I, you want to insert it there, right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code aligns two lists on the same tab, shifting one side or the other down so that the values in Column A and Column I match:

```
Sub Aligner()

    Dim wst As Worksheet
    Set wst = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim curRow As Long
    curRow = 4
    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = wst.UsedRange.Rows.Count * 2
    
    Dim AcctA As String
    Dim AcctI As String
    AcctA = CStr(wst.Cells(curRow, 1))
    AcctI = CStr(wst.Cells(curRow, 9))
    
    Do
        With wst
        
            If AcctA <> AcctI Then
            
                Dim spA As Integer
                Dim spI As Integer
                spA = InStr(AcctA, " ")
                spI = InStr(AcctI, " ")
                
                If spA > 1 Then
                    AcctA = Left$(AcctA, spA - 1)
                End If
                If spI > 1 Then
                    AcctI = Left$(AcctI, spI - 1)
                End If
                
                If AcctA > AcctI Then
                    .Range(.Cells(curRow, 1), .Cells(curRow, 5)).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                    .Cells(curRow, 1) = .Cells(curRow, 9)
                Else
                    .Cells(curRow, 9).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                    .Cells(curRow, 1) = .Cells(curRow, 1)
                End If
                
            End If
            
            curRow = curRow + 1
            
            AcctA = CStr(wst.Cells(curRow, 1))
            AcctI = CStr(wst.Cells(curRow, 9))
            
        End With
    Loop Until curRow >= lastRow

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        A = ("A" & x)
        I = ("I" & x)

            If I <> A Then Range("I" & x).Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
```

As shown from your code I will never equal A because you are assigning "Ax" to A and "Ix" to I, so I not equal to A will always be TRUE!

Comment: CMart14, if it answers your question please consider marking this as the answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer.